# Bidistributive implies boolean algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

Honestly I'm not sure if this question is appropriate here so I will likely remove it after I get an answer unless I am told otherwise.

This comment on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/svtkv3/how_do_ivy_league_undergraduate_get_through_high/hxjklsr/ mentions a paper stating that distributivity of addition over multiplication implies a boolean algebra.

However, I cannot see any proof of this and in fact it seems like it is false as De
Morgan algebras are not boolean algebras and yet satisy distributivity in addition and multiplication.

I am curious if anyone knows what paper might be being talked about here, or otherwise knows what structure the statement might be true over. Any information would be helpful as I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered as it is. As you pointed out, there are algebraic structures with two binary operations each of which distributing over the other and which are not Boolean algebras (any distributive lattice will do it, and de Morgan algebras are "kind of" a subclass of these). If you need to proof that both distributive laws imply Boolean, then you need some more specific context.

Comment: @amrsa Fair enough, it did seem unlikely to be correct. Thanks for replying though as I couldn't be sure that I hadn't overlooked something.